# Looking for a voice recording software with visualizer

Tags: audio, data-visualization

I am looking for a software that will let me record my voice and create a video with visualizer (correct me if my choice of words is wrong) that is sensitive to my voice like TV professionals show on screen when they do not have a video footage to go with it. A wave that moves up and down when the person is speaking and comes to rest when there's no audio activity.

Here's an example of what I want as the end product (see how it's jumps only when the music is playing):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBYjZV74iYE

but a lot more formal and preferably in the form of waves.

I'd like the piece of software to be able to take in sound in the form of a .aac or .mp3, and output the video in .avi, .mp4, or .avi. I'm quite flexible with the format, though, and I'm happy to convert files between formats.

I use Windows, OS X, and Linux, so OS isn't really a problem.

Comment: We'll need quite a bit more information to provide a solid recommendation - what OS are you using? What type of audio file do you have? What format should the output be in?

Comment: I use Linux, Windows and Mac so OS isn't an issue for me as long as the s/w is close to perfect. My audio file will be in mp3 or wav format (I do not mind converting). Ideally, I would like a software that will capture my voice and output a video with visualization. Please let me know if anything else is ambiguous. Cheers

Comment: If this question is clear enough, can you please remove put it off hold? It tells me - "`As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.`" Why is it so hard to tell what I am asking?

Comment: I have even provided an example of what a visualizer is.

Comment: You're almost there. What *format*. (wav, mp3, etc.) do you want to put in to the app, and what format do you want out (mov, mp4, etc.)? Once you answer those questions, I think we can reopen it.

Comment: Thanks my friend. Input format will most likely be .aac or .mp3 and for output, I am desiring any of the popular video format - avi, mp4 or flv. (overall, I am quite flexible with formats as I am happy to convert)

Comment: Awesome, I just reopened it. Could you review my edits and make sure that I accurately represented your needs?

Comment: What's wrong with the inbuilt sound recorder of Windows? As you are willing to convert the formats by yourself using other software?

Comment: There's nothing wrong as such, it just doesn't add a visualizer that I am after.

Comment: I won't make it a reply because I don't know where to find the software, and it's designed for music rather than voice, but [Partitura](http://www.abstractbirds.com/34019/335543/projects/partitura) seems amazing!

Comment: Partitura looks good but it's a custom software and I could not find a download link to try it.
I am not sure if it's the same tool but I found this in their description: `A tool for displaying scanned musical sheets The music scrolls as a continuous stream over the PC screen. The position of the staves on the page are automatically detected. Repetitions in the piece can be easily configured.`
They do not say anywhere that it will visualize audio files. I found it here → http://sourceforge.net/projects/partituramagica/

Comment: Nope, partitura means music-sheet, which explains the numerous tools called so.

Comment: Here's another video with a good example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1R2oE7mvXw

Answer (score 1):

[Spectrum3D](http://spectrum3d.sourceforge.net/) runs on Ubuntu and can analyze an audio file or microphone input in real time. Unfortunately it doesn't support video recording so you'll have to use a screen recorder. I recommend [Kazam](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kazam/).

Here is a screenshot of Spectrum3D from its official site:

[image]

Comment: I did not wanted to use screen recorder + media player combination and have kept that as my last resort if I can not find a specific software that allows me to do this.

Comment: @vDog Adobe AfterEffects should work http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuAEJRHQKug

Comment: TY for that. Unfortunately it takes too long to render. That 3 minute song took 4.5hrs to render. My projects range from 5 - 20 minutes so still looking for a better alternative.